# How to wait for data from various observables to perform an action

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have a problem in angular. I want to get data from various observables and take action after all data arrives.

I already tried separately the methods to get address and data Person and if they work well, I leave the example for the case of getting address.

```
getDireccion() {
    this.store
        .select('direccion')
        .subscribe(({ direccion }) => (this.direccion = direccion))
        .unsubscribe();
}
```

But now I want to make sure that all the address data and Person data are already there to be able to carry out another action, that's why I'm using forkJoin, but it doesn't work well for me, it doesn't execute the `console.log ('responses ==>', response);`

```
forkJoin([ 
    this.store.select('direccion'),
    this.store.select('datosPersona')
]).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log('respuestas ==> ', response);
});
```

I am using ngrx for state handling

Comment: Esta pagina es para ingles, si puede cambiar la idioma nos podemos ayudarte

Comment: Try using english

Comment: SO is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site, and either translate your question (including title!) into English, or else post it on the [Spanish Stackoverflow site](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `combineLatest`, if you want to do something if it changes during the component life cycle, or only select it once by using `take(1)`. The reason it's not working, is because `forkJoin` waits for the observable to complete and a store `select` never really completes:

```
combineLatest([ 
    this.store.select('direccion'),
    this.store.select('datosPersona')
]).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log('respuestas ==> ', response);
});
```

---

```
forkJoin([ 
    this.store.select('direccion').pipe(take(1)),
    this.store.select('datosPersona').pipe(take(1))
]).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log('respuestas ==> ', response);
});
```